# What does it mean that two frames are " in a state of constant, rectilinear motion with respect to one another"?

Tags: classical-mechanics, inertial-frames, definition, relative-motion, galilean-relativity

This expression ( applied to reference frames) " being in a state of constant, rectilinear motion with respect to one another "is frequently used as self explanatory . Though I might appear as stupid, I absolutely do not understand what it means!

I perfectly understand what means " rectilinear" motion and " constant " motion, when applied to a single motion . But I would like to know what it means to say that 2 states of motion are " rectilinear and constant " ***to one*** ***another***".

Does this mean that 2 frames are " in a state of constant.... " just in case they are following parallel lines  in the same sense, with the same constant speed?

Is it possible, please, to formulate ***precisely*** the definition of " in a state of rectilinear and constant motion to one another" as a ***list of distinct conditions that are individually necessary and jointly sufficient?***

Comment: Thanks to you all for these clear and detailed answers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that the reference frame $K$ has **constant rectilinear  motion with respect to the reference frame** $K'$ means that if you consider a point $p$ at rest in $K$, the *velocity* of that point computed in $K'$

*(a) is constant in time* and

*(b) it does not depend on the position of $p$  at rest in the first reference frame.*

It turns out that, wirh the definition above, to have constant rectilinear motion is an equivalence relation among reference frames.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to talk of a "single motion" of a particle, and what is meant is its motion with respect to a particular reference frame (the specifics of which may be tacitly understood). But it doesn't make sense to talk of a "single motion" of a reference frame - a reference frame always moves with respect to another reference frame.

One way to define "a state of constant, rectilinear motion with respect to one another" between frames $A$ and $B$: **any particle with a fixed location when viewed in $A$ moves in a straight line with constant velocity when viewed in $B$, and this velocity is the same for all such particles**. The other direction (swapping $A$ with $B$) follows from this mathematically, so there's no need to tack a "and vice versa" at the end.

A reference frame can be specified by a set of reference points, e.g. to specify a reference frame in 3 dimensions it's enough to fix the origin and the points at positive distance 1 from the origin on each of the 3 axes, the total of 4 points. A more economical way to define "a state of constant, rectilinear motion with respect to one another" is then to say that *all the reference points* of $A$ are moving with the same constant velocity in $B$, and vice versa (again, the "vice versa" is strictly speaking redudant).

Intuitively, imagine a reference frame as a trio of $x,y,z$ rays starting from the same point, the origin, located somewhere in space. Imagine two such frames, as if they were rigid physical things, located in space next to each other, but not necessarily parallel to each other. Hold one of them in place and send the other moving in some direction with constant velocity without rotation. The two frames are now "in a state of constant, rectilinear motion with respect to one another". If one of them is rotating even a little bit with respect to the other, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

> But I would like to know what it means to say that 2 states of motion
>   are " rectilinear and constant " to one another".

It means that all inertial frames are in a state of constant, rectilinear motion with respect to one another.

> Does this mean that 2 frames are " in a state of constant.... " just
>   in case they are following parallel lines in the same sense, with the
>   same constant speed?

Basically yes. An inertial frame is one which is not itself accelerating. But the frames do not necessarily have to be in "parallel lines". Their motions could be perpendicular to each other. That will result in different magnitudes of relative motions. The equivalence of inertial frames does not mean the relative motion between all inertial frames will be the same, just that those relative motions will be both rectilinear and constant.

> Is it possible, please, to formulate precisely the definition of " in
>   a state of rectilinear and constant motion to one another" as a list
>   of distinct conditions that are individually necessary and jointly
>   sufficient?

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a "list of distinct conditions". But I think you can say that main necessary and sufficient condition for all inertial frames to be equivalent is that there can be no net forces operating on any of the frames which would result in an acceleration.

Another way of saying this is the equivalence of inertial frames means if you are a closed box in an inertial frame, it should not be possible not be possible for you to determine, by any experiment whatsoever, the absolute velocity of the box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bod D. It does help, thanks!